# FSM transition table from verilog code

Tags: verilog

I'm looking at this verilog code and it asks me to do a state transition table

[image]

This is the answer, but it's using x=a and z=b and q=y.

[image]

the thing i don't understand is why in the code does it say assign q = state 1 or state 3, but in the transition table shouldn't it be y=1 in state 1 and 3? they have y=1 in state 1 and 2.

Answer (score -1):

1. What you called "the answer" I'd call a state diagram, not a state transition table. If the question asks you to produce a state transition table, I would not expect this diagram to be an acceptable answer.
2. I agree with you that the outputs shown in the diagram don't match the Verilog code. You'll need to read your assignment carefully or check with your instructor to find out which states are supposed to produce a high output in your table.

Comment: so just to confirm, if i want the code to correspond with the state diagram, i would have to make the code say q= state 1 | state 2?

Comment: You would need to output high in states 1 and 2. However, what you suggested is not valid Verilog to get that result.

Comment: why is it not valid, sorry, can u explain

Comment: Because `state 1 | state 2` is not valid Verilog syntax. Notice in the original code they used `(state == S0) | (state == S1)`, not `state 0 | state 1`.